# Shopify - I want to remove "buy it now" and "add to cart" button from the theme template on some product pages. How can I achieve that?

Tags: shopify

I want to edit the product theme template to remove the "buy it now" and "add to cart" buttons from some products.

How can I achieve that? Need suggestion on it.

Comment: You can use either meta fields or tags on products,[Metafields](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield), [tags](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/shopify-admin/productivity-tools/using-tags)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you'd like to remove "Add to cart" button from some products?
If that is the case, you could do this using some tags. Something like:

```
{% if product.tags contains 'your-tag' %}

   {% comment %} Something here {% endcomment %}
{% else %}
  {% comment %} Add to cart button {% endcomment %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a tag called something like:

**hide--add-to-cart**

and find the add to cart button inside **product.liquid** and place it like:

```
{% unless product.tags contains 'hide--add-to-cart' %}
    place here your add to cart button
{% endif %}
```